# Python read next()

Tags: python

`next()` in python does not work. What is an alternative to reading next line in Python? Here is a sample:

```
filne = "D:/testtube/testdkanimfilternode.txt"
f = open(filne, 'r+')

while 1:
    lines = f.readlines()
    if not lines:
        break
    for line in lines:
        print line
        if (line[:5] == "anim "):
            print 'next() '
            ne = f.next()
            print ' ne ',ne,'\n'
            break

f.close()
```

Running this on a file does not show 'ne '.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`next()` does not work in your case because you first call `readlines()` which basically sets the file iterator to point to the end of file.

Since you are reading in all the lines anyway you can refer to the next line using an index:

```
filne = "in"
with open(filne, 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in range(0, len(lines)):
        line = lines[i]
        print line
        if line[:5] == "anim ":
            ne = lines[i + 1] # you may want to check that i < len(lines)
            print ' ne ',ne,'\n'
            break
```

Answer (score 39):

When you do : `f.readlines()` you already read all the file so `f.tell()` will show you that you are in the end of the file, and doing `f.next()` will result in a `StopIteration` error.

Alternative of what you want to do is:

```
filne = "D:/testtube/testdkanimfilternode.txt"

with open(filne, 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("anim "):
            print f.next() 
            # Or use next(f, '') to return <empty string> instead of raising a  
            # StopIteration if the last line is also a match.
            break
```

Comment: For Python 3, use `print(next(f))` instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
lines = f.readlines()
```

reads all the lines of the file f. So it makes sense that there aren't any more line to read in the file f.
If you want to read the file line by line, use readline().

Answer (score 4):

A small change to your algorithm:

```
filne = "D:/testtube/testdkanimfilternode.txt"
f = open(filne, 'r+')

while 1:
    lines = f.readlines()
    if not lines:
        break
    line_iter= iter(lines) # here
    for line in line_iter: # and here
        print line
        if (line[:5] == "anim "):
            print 'next() '
            ne = line_iter.next() # and here
            print ' ne ',ne,'\n'
            break

f.close()
```

However, using the `pairwise` function from [`itertools` recipes](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return itertools.izip(a, b)
```

you can change your loop into:

```
for line, next_line in pairwise(f): # iterate over the file directly
    print line
    if line.startswith("anim "):
        print 'next() '
        print ' ne ', next_line, '\n'
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to read the next line, you are iterating through the lines. **lines** is a list (an array), and **for line in lines** is iterating over it. Every time you are finished with one you move onto the next line. If you want to skip to the next line just **continue** out of the current loop.

```
filne = "D:/testtube/testdkanimfilternode.txt"
f = open(filne, 'r+')

lines = f.readlines() # get all lines as a list (array)

# Iterate over each line, printing each line and then move to the next
for line in lines:
    print line

f.close()
```

Comment: and as vitaut says you have already read the entire file using f.readlines. You are not iterating over the file, the entire file has been read into memory.

Answer (score -1):

```
file = '../input/testtxt/kaggle.txt'
output = []
con = 'Image for'
with open(file, 'r') as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines() #reading line by line
    for i in range(0, len(lines)):
#         print(lines[i]) 
        if(con in lines[i]): #condition matching
            output.append(lines[i + 1]) #match content
    print(output)
```