# merging csv files with python goes wrong

Tags: python, csv

So I'm using the following code:

```
def printname(x,m,y,n,z,R):
    name = x + str(m) + y + str(n) +  z + str(R)  + ".csv"
    return name

fout=open("out.csv","a")

for k in [0.9, 0.8, 0.75, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1]:# n
    for j in [0.,5.,10.,30.,70.,80.,100.]: # R  
        f = open(printname("minTm",0.0,"n",k,"R",j))
        f.next() # skip the header
        for line in f:
            fout.write(line)
        f.close() # not really needed
fout.close()
```

I'm using the function printname to create the filenames which have the form of minTm0.0nkRj
where k and j iterate as shown in the for loop above.

All works well with the merged file, only that I lose the first line of my csv files. Example of a csv file follow:

```
m=,0.0,R=,0.0

Tmin,Tmax,s,a,tmp
5000,10000.0,[ -4.06784730e-10],[ 1.5],0.0060940149762198454
7500,10000.0,[ 0.],[ 1.5],0.0058371331958134804
8750,10000.0,[ -2.00167591e-06],[ 1.5],0.0057109512367820173
9375,10000.0,[ -5.81705152e-06],[ 1.5],0.0056484231992318433
9687,10000.0,[ 0.],[ 1.5],0.0056173494163291524
9843,10000.0,[ -9.33496371e-16],[ 1.5],0.0056018475131042059
9921,10000.0,[ -8.29812062e-15],[ 1.5],0.0055941053050743194
9960,10000.0,[ -3.01889438e-06],[ 1.5],0.0055902363865212969
9980,10000.0,[ -5.86201413e-06],[ 1.5],0.0055882528908336284
9990,10000.0,[ -2.57259293e-18],[ 1.5],0.0055872612866520906
9995,10000.0,[ -8.29261958e-08],[ 1.5],0.0055867655204772633
9997,10000.0,[ -4.17256457e-06],[ 1.5],0.0055865672207120942
9998,10000.0,[ -6.70360888e-06],[ 1.5],0.0055864680722669735
9999,10000.0,[ -1.02650006e-11],[ 1.5],0.0055863689247764216
,
Tmin= ,9999,s=,[ -1.02650006e-11],a=,[ 1.5],tmp=,0.0055863689247764216
```

The first line which shows the value of m, R is vital for the final file. And I can't seem to think of any reason that the algorithm omits it. Any ideas? Did run the code without the line `f.next()` and got the same result.

Comment: `next` should be used when a file is iterated. It's not the good use that you have done ([see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213063/python-read-next))

Comment: Well, even without `next` the first line disappears..Thanks for the link anyways.

Comment: Is the `m=,0.0,R=,0.0` and the blank line following it part of each csv file?

Comment: Yes, each file has the structure as above.

Comment: In that case you should skip the first three lines of each input file, otherwise you're _not_ creating a proper csv output file. However you might want to manually add a `Tmin,Tmax,s,a,tmp` header line to it before copying just the lines of data from each of the others.

Comment: It might be so. But with the solution posted below I got a totally normal csv file, readable by Libreoffice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it:

```
fout=open("out.csv","a")
for k in [0.9, 0.8, 0.75, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1]:# n
    for j in [0.,5.,10.,30.,70.,80.,100.]: # R  
        f = open(printname("minTm",0.0,"n",k,"R",j), 'r+')
        lines = f.readlines()
        for i in range(0, len(lines)):
            line = lines[i]
            fout.write(line)
fout.close()
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In the output file, do you lose the first line for ALL input files?  Because it seems like, if you take out the `f.next()` line in your code, the first line of the input should be output, but it might be appended to the last line of the previous input entry.  If this is the case, you may try to just add a extra line break after you read in each input file:

```
for k in [0.9, 0.8, 0.75, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1]:# n
for j in [0.,5.,10.,30.,70.,80.,100.]: # R  
    f = open(printname("minTm",0.0,"n",k,"R",j))
    for line in f:
        fout.write(line)
    fout.write('\n')
    f.close() # not really needed
fout.close()
```

Comment: I lose the first line for *all* input files, yes. Thanks for the suggestion but it won't cut it.