# Parsing of EOF, Python 3

Tags: python, strip

Sorry for obviously silly question, I am just far not a pro. I was curious how it happens, that for the code in Python 3.5 just below I receive IndexError,

```
with open('graph.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()

for i in range(len(Text)):
    if text[i+1] == '>':
       *do something*
```

> line 5: if text[i+1] == '>':
>   IndexError: string index out of range

However, when I `strip` the file's reading

> `text = f.read().strip()`

compiler is happy. In any scenarios, I hit EOF but with the latter it is parsed well.

Thanks a mil!

EDIT: For those who are gonna read over these lines one day, please don't read it further cause the bug was in the code I didn't present. However, to leave a bit of utility, please remember that `.strip()` function cuts by default all trailing whitespace (i.e. spaces and newlines). That was partly the reason of my problem. Cheers!

Comment: Your `i` index goes all the way to the last character in the string. You try to access `Text[i+1]`. Hence `IndexError`.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more info, and good luck with your code!

Comment: Thank you! It's nice to be here and all the best for you as well!

Comment: very well said @cxw

Comment: It's concentional in Python to name variables like 'Text' using lower case only. Usually, only class names have an initial capital. Hugs!

Comment: I cannot see how adding the `.strip()` will really fix the IndexError, unless graph.txt is all whitespace, so Text is being stripped down to 0 characters long.

Comment: @Ivan_G don't forget to use pep8 as formatting

Comment: @ Andy K many thanks yet again! I did not quite know about, but will do my best to follow it from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because indexes in `Text` run from `0` to `len(Text)-1`.  Similarly, the output of `range()` runs from `0` to the parameter minus one, here `len(Text)-1`.  Therefore, the very last time through the loop, the `if` statement indexes `Text[len(Text)-1 + 1] = Text[len(Text)]`, which doesn't exist, leading to an `IndexError`.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! But my question was rather why I don't get IndexError when I strip the reading.

Comment: @Ivan_G You have not posted enough code to demonstrate that behaviour. It depends on what the rest of your code says and what your file contains.

Comment: The behaviour remains regardless what I put below (even just let' say with count+=1) and my file contains just two short lines

Answer (score 1):

Be aware, a more Pythonic way of doing this, that makes it impossible to make these sort of 'off by one' string indexing errors, is:

```
for char in Text:
    if char == '>':
       # do something
```

If your 'do something' needs access to 'i', the index where 'char' occurs, then this becomes:

```
for i, char in enumerate(Text):
    if char == '>':
       # do something with i
```

It seems, from your code, like you don't want to check for '>' characters in the 0th position, i.e. Text[0]. Hence:

```
for i, char in enumerate(Text):
    if i > 0 and char == '>':
       # do something with i
```

Comment: Jonathan, thank you very much for such an illuminating answer. Pythonic way is an elegant one.

Comment: You are welcome, I'm enjoying my time in Python-land too. Upvotes are a great way to express thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe do something along the same lines of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213063/python-read-next).

Also I noticed when you opened the file you did not tell it how to open `open('graph.txt', 'r')`. Maybe that is part of the issue as well

Also you are gonna want to make sure that you loop all the way up to the full length so you will need to say in `range(0, len(text))`

Comment: Hi @brodie, it is always good to have a definitive answer where people can build things. If you want to advice, comments are very useful for that.

Comment: @Andy thanks for the edit and advice Andy. As per stack overflow rules i cannot comment until I have 50 reputation. Other wise i would have. Thank you though